# Error with VLC when I want to fast forward the video

Tags: intel-graphics, vlc

There is an error with VLC when I want to fast forward the video or jump to a certain point in time it closes unexpectedly, I have searched everywhere but there is no solution, I leave the screenshot of the problem.

The video does play and the audio is heard well, it only happens when you want to jump to a point in the video.

Configuration:

VLC media player 3.0.16

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

Intel Corporation RocketLake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 750] (rev 04)

Linux 6.2.0-36-generic

[image: Error VLC]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but a work-around: set the **Hardware-accelerated decoding** option to **disable** in *Tools -> Preferences -> Input/Codecs*, this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the "VA-API video decoder via DRM" configuration and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware-accelerated decoding disabling works

Updates just arrived and Hardware-accelerated decoding automatic working again

apt apt-transport-https apt-utils ffmpeg firefox firefox-locale-en google-chrome-stable libapt-pkg6.0 libavcodec-dev libavcodec-extra
libavcodec-extra58 libavdevice-dev libavdevice58 libavfilter-dev libavfilter7 libavformat-dev libavformat58 libavresample4 libavutil-dev
libavutil56 libfido2-1 libpostproc-dev libpostproc55 libprocps8 libswresample-dev libswresample3 libswscale-dev libswscale5 procps python-pip-whl python3-pip traceroute

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks, I update and working again.